# I'm getting a lock alert when trying to connect/add elements to the viewcontroller in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

I have a ViewController that all of the sudden will not allow me to add a new element or connect an existing element to an IBAction. I've looked through sample code as well and googled the s*%& out of it without finding a solution.

My ViewController.swift file contains this code:

@IBAction func helpButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

And I'm trying to connect a very basic button.

Also, note that I've double-checked to be sure that all elements and views are set to Lock: Nothing.

Any help would be amazing!

[image]

Comment: Check that the custom class in the storyboard inspector for the View Controller is set to the name of your view controller.

Comment: Yep. I've double-checked that. Both the custom class is ViewController, and the name of the view controller is ViewController. Also, all existing elements are still connected and working properly. It's just I can't add/edit any elements in the ViewController

Comment: What do you mean by a lock alert? Try cleaning Xcode's derived data and then exiting Xcode. You'd be amazed how many Xcode problems can be solved by simply re-launching it.

Comment: Dang. Tried that too, but no luck. The "lock alert" is just me referencing the lock icon that pops up when I try to connect the button Touch Up Inside to the code reference. (It's the lock image overlay in the image I attached to this question).

Comment: What about just changing/adding things in that file? Can you edit the file?

Comment: Yes, I can change/add things to the ViewController.swift file, but can't do anything interacting with the storyboard view. (I also have no errors etc in the swift file and it builds and runs successfully)

Comment: It really looks like a localization lock. Are you sure the menu Editor > Localization Locking is on Nothing?

Comment: @EricD That was exactly it! It was set to "All Properties". I changed to "Nothing", and it's working now. Thanks so much. You are a life-saver!

Comment: Cool! You're welcome. I've made my comment into an answer so that you can "accept" it and the question will be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to menu **Editor** then **Localization Locking** then choose **Nothing**.

You probably have enabled one of the other locking options accidentally.